# How to SAVE browser cache after every Appium automated tests to avoid logging in at every test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, appium

This is actully an Answer: when running appium tests purely using BrowserName capability, appium clears cache after every test which makes it impossible to run continuos tests without logging in at every test.

The answer is you need to simply add ChromeOption "setExperimentalOption("androidKeepAppDataDir", true);" to your Desired Capabilities and this acts similar to the user profile option - addArguments("user-data-dir=") for Desktop tests.

A full code snippet of the Desired capabilities initialisation example:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("androidKeepAppDataDir", true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
cap.setCapability("deviceName","your device's name");
cap.setCapability("udid","your device's udid");
cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion","10");
cap.setCapability("browserName","Chrome");
cap.setCapability (MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity","*");
cap.setCapability("skipServerInstallation",true);
cap.setCapability("noReset",true);
cap.setCapability("dontStopAppOnReset", false);
url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver.set(new AppiumDriver(url,cap));
```

Tried to running appium tests without having to log in at each test